# Python + Indexing over range of tuples not returning expected result

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't return the 3rd element.

```
Input:
t = [(3,300),(1,100),(2,200),(4,400),(5,500)]
t.sort()
print(t)
t = t[0:2]
print(t)

Output:
[(1, 100), (2, 200), (3, 300), (4, 400), (5, 500)]
[(1, 100), (2, 200)]
```

Thanks!  And sorry for the simple question.  I would have expected the result to be:
[(1, 100), (2, 200),(3,300)]

Comment: Because `a[i:j]` is `i` **included** and `j` **excluded**. That is *slice notation*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Your first instinct here should be to [check the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)... not post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is like this `A[a:b]` where A is an array, a is the *start point*  (zero indexed and an integer), and b is the *stop point* (also an integer and zero indexed). The last element in the selection, IE the one found at the stop point, is not captured so if the stop point is the same as the start point, no elements are captured.

So if I have `A=[0,1,2,3]` and type `A[0:0]` I get `[]`. But If I type `A[0:1]` I get `[0]`. Note that `A[:1]` is the same as `A[0:1]` is the same as `[A[1]]`. If you just want the first 3 elements, try `A[:3]`.

**What's happening?**

Underneath, when you call object[a:b:c] it is interpreted as `object.__getitem__( slice(a, b, c) )`.
Note that the slice class has the following instantiation call: `slice(start, stop, step)`. This allows it to skip over elements or reverse order if you give it a negative step and switch the start and stop. So `A[slice(None,None,-1)]` is the same as `A[::-1]` which selects the entire array by iterating through it backwards, thus returning the entire list in reverse order. For more on slice notation see: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation/509295#509295)

Answer (score 0):

Python indices start from 0, so if you need the first three you would need the items at `t[0], t[1] and t[2]`. you should do as follows.

```
t = [(3,300),(1,100),(2,200),(4,400),(5,500)]
t.sort()
print(t)
t = t[0:3]
print(t)
```